# Logging modules in Mathematica?

Tags: scripting, debugging

Is there any **logging module** or functions or scripts that one can use to store all the information of what happens during executing mathematica program in Wolfram?

For example, one might look up log.txt file to see whether there are any errors during running.

Thank you very much for any hints! thank you!